# How to parse this type of XML data in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing

How do I parse `enclosure_details` attributes? Here is my XML output.

```
<enclosure>
                    <enclosure_details url="http://cdn..com/media/gallery/p18gmcacuj1o4n1572b1m1qnel1c6.jpg" length="12345" type="image/jpeg" title=<![CDATA[]]> description=<![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;Mergers and acquisitions have gained steam in early 2014. Here is a rundown of the whole-bank deals, shedding of noncore businesses and swapping of securities so far this year.&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P align=&quot;right&quot;&gt;&lt;em&gt;Image: Thinkstock&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;]]> />
                    <enclosure_details url="http://cdn..com/media/gallery/p18gmcacuj1527me8acrk2r7td7.jpg" length="12345" type="image/jpeg" title=<![CDATA[Carolina Domino Effect?]]> description=<![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;VantageSouth in Raleigh, N.C., and Yadkin Financial in Elkin, N.C., announced plans in late January for &lt;a href=&quot;http://www..com/issues/179_18/vantagesouth-yadkin-deal-could-spur-meaningful-ma-in-north-carolina-1065227-1.html&quot;&gt;a $300 million merger&lt;/a&gt;. VantageSouth CEO Scott Custer will lead the bank. The MOE is expected to force other North Carolina banks to decide whether to become buyers or sellers.&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P align=&quot;right&quot;&gt;&lt;em&gt;Bloomberg News&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;]]> />
                    <enclosure_details url="http://cdn..com/media/gallery/p18gmcacuj332qvhj7c1qbucn98.jpg" length="12345" type="image/jpeg" title=<![CDATA[Cost-Cutting Focus]]> description=<![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;ConnectOne in Englewood, N.J., is merging with Center Bancorp in Union, N.J., in &lt;a href=&quot;http://www..com/video/connectone-ceo-explains-banks-merger-with-center-of-nj1065072-1.html&quot;&gt;another MOE-like deal&lt;/a&gt; that would create a $3 billion-asset bank and is meant to produce $7 million in annual cost savings. Frank Sorrentino of ConnectOne will become the CEO.&lt;/p&gt;]]> />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try NSXMLParser for iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html

And you have a tutorial here: http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2011/08/parsing-xml-using-nsxmlparser.html

This delegate method get you the string inside the tag

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
}
```

This method gets you the attribute in your case the url inside enclosure_details

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundAttributeDeclarationWithName:(NSString *)attributeName forElement:(NSString *)elementName type:(NSString *)type defaultValue:(NSString *)defaultValue;
```

Comment: i have implement same Parser, but when i get this data, i dont know how to access..
<enclosure>
<enclosure_details url="http://cdn..com/media/gallery/p18gmcacuj1o4n1572b1m1qnel1c6.jpg" length="12345" type="image/jpeg" title=<![CDATA[]]> description=<![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;Mergers and acquisitions have gained steam in early 2014. Here is a rundown of the whole-bank deals, shedding of noncore businesses and swapping of securities so far this year.&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P align=&quot;right&quot;&gt;&lt;em&gt;Image: Thinkstock&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;]]> />

Comment: NSXMLParser has a delegate methods, and it will return you the value of this tag. please follow the link

Comment: yes sir, same i use both links for parsing, but i cant have this idea, how to implement ?
I want to access all content of <enclosure_details> but i have no idea, how to do? Here is my code, 
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"])
        {
                NSString * name = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"enclosure_details"];
                [item setObject:name forKey:@"articleEnclosure"];
        }

Comment: i never use XML parser, so i have no idea. can you give me some demo code ?

Comment: mostly i am using JSON parsing, and XML parsing too.. but in XML parsing i never do like that issue.. anyone suggest me ?

Comment: here is another tutorial http://iosbala.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-using-nsxmlparser-in-iphone-sdk.html